# How to autoplay video with sound if that possible if not then mute and show button to unmute?

Tags: video, autoplay

I need something similar on Brightcove Player Sample: Autoplay with Unmute Button, but not for video-js, but for video. How to do this with this code?

```
<div class="video-fallback"></div>
<video id="video" onloadstart="this.volume=0.6" loop="" autoplay="">
<source src="" type="video/mp4">
<script type="text/javascript">
  var videos2 = [
  'video4.mp4',
  'video5.mp4',
  'video6.mp4'
  ];
  var count = Math.floor(Math.random() * videos2.length);
  document.getElementsByTagName('source')[0].src = './videos/' + videos2[count];
  </script>
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

> *"I need something similar to Brightcove Player Sample: Autoplay with Unmute Button, but not for video-js, but for video. How to do this with this code?"*

You need to search for a tutorial: example [html5 overlay big button](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=html5+overlay+big+button).

As a starting point to give you ideas, you can test this code shown below:
 (*eg:* test on [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video) code previewer)...

It uses CSS Styling (see: `style=" "`) to put the "unmute" button on a layer (`z-index`) above the video. Investigate the other style options like `position` and `top` and `left` to find settings that help to fix your problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div class="video-fallback">

<img id="icon_big_mute"
onclick="mute_big_click()"
src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/21/Speaker_Icon.svg/120px-Speaker_Icon.svg.png"
width="200"  height="200" style="position: absolute; z-index: 1; top: 40px; left:50px" />

<video id="video" muted loop autoplay />
<source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

</div>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

var videos2 = [
'video4.mp4',
'video5.mp4',
'video6.mp4'
];

var count = Math.floor(Math.random() * videos2.length);

var myVid = document.getElementById('video');
var btn = document.getElementById('icon_big_mute');

function mute_big_click()
{
    myVid.muted = false;
    btn.style.visibility = "hidden";
}

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: I need something like this https://codepen.io/team/rcrooks1969/pen/jzmWzL here the video is played with sound if the browser allows it, and if not, then it is muted and with the unmute button. But it doesn't work for me, because there is "video-js" attribute, but I need for "video".

Comment: watch with sound https://imgur.com/a/XWe98Gh . This is what I need, but I need to remake it for my code

Comment: Sorry for late response. I am not understanding the issue... If you want an autoplay video, you do that with mute enabled until the user tells browser to enable sound (via a click)... If you have extra conditions then use an IF statement. You'll have to **(1)** Listen for page load event then on "load" you (a) play the video (b) start a Timer **(2)** Check after timer's 1 second (1000ms) if the video is playing (it will be paused if the browser does not allow it), then use another IF to check if paused where you then show the unmute button, enable video mute, play the video (in silent mode)..

Comment: Yes, you got it right. But I'm not very strong in js to do this.

Comment: So, do you know how to do it?